# Пунктуация обстоятельства дополнения

Tags: пунктуация, дополнение

*"Пример моделирования конформаций **одновременно двух** макромолекул длиной в 1000 нм"*

Нужна ли здесь запятая или, может, дефис?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни запятая, ни дефис не нужны.

Comment: Ну где-то в районе выделенных слов, по-моему вполне понятно

Comment: Когда я отвечал, выделенных слов не было. Или в телефоне не отображается.

Comment: Не, походу на телефоне не отображается